SPFx Extension COMMAND_1 to call a function
I'm trying to add an action to the context menu in my SharePoint library. The action appears when I right-click on a file, but when I click on the action, the default window pops up and not the function I thought I routed it to.
/src/extensions/helloWorld/HelloWorldCommandSets.ts
      public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'COMMAND_1':
        console.log('command_1');
        this.myfunction1();
        break;
      case 'COMMAND_2':
        console.log('command_2');
        this.myfunction2();
        break;
      default:
        throw new Error('Unknown command');
    }
  }

The console log doesn't trigger nor does the function. Below is the onInit function that is a part of the same file.
      public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'Initialized HelloWorldCommandSet');
    // initial state of the command's visibility
    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    compareOneCommand.visible = false;
    const compareTwoCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');
    compareTwoCommand.visible = true;

    this.context.listView.listViewStateChangedEvent.add(this, this._onListViewStateChanged);

    return Promise.resolve();
  }

If other information is required to help in answering the question, please let me know and I will provide it ASAP. Thank you.
Entire code:
import { Log } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  BaseListViewCommandSet,
  type Command,
  type IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters,
  type ListViewStateChangedEventArgs
} from '@microsoft/sp-listview-extensibility';
import { Dialog } from '@microsoft/sp-dialog';
export interface ISendEmailSPFxWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  url: string;
}


/**
 * If your command set uses the ClientSideComponentProperties JSON input,
 * it will be deserialized into the BaseExtension.properties object.
 * You can define an interface to describe it.
 */
export interface IHelloWorldCommandSetProperties {
  // This is an example; replace with your own properties
  sampleTextOne: string;
  sampleTextTwo: string;
}

const LOG_SOURCE: string = 'HelloWorldCommandSet';
declare var SP;
export default class HelloWorldCommandSet extends BaseListViewCommandSet<IHelloWorldCommandSetProperties> {
  public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'Initialized HelloWorldCommandSet');
    // initial state of the command's visibility
    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    compareOneCommand.visible = false;
    const compareTwoCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_2');
    compareTwoCommand.visible = true;

    this.context.listView.listViewStateChangedEvent.add(this, this._onListViewStateChanged);

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  
  public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
    switch (event.itemId) {
      case 'COMMAND_1':
        console.log('command_1');
        this.myfunction1();
        break;
      case 'COMMAND_2':
        console.log('command_2');
        this.myfunction2();
        break;
    }
  }
   // logic for getting file ID
   private getSelectedFileId(): string | null {
    try {
      const context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
      const selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
      if (selectedItems.length > 0) {
        const selectedItemId = selectedItems[0].id;
        return selectedItemId.toString();
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error getting selected file ID:', error);
      return null;
    }
  }

  private myfunction1(): void {
    alert("Function has triggered properly");
    const flowEndpointUrl = "UrlToMyPAFlow"
    const fileId = this.getSelectedFileId();
    if (fileId) {
      const requestOptions: RequestInit = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          fileId: fileId
        })
      };
      fetch(flowEndpointUrl, requestOptions).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          Dialog.alert("Submission Successful");
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to trigger flow');
        }
      });
    }
  }

  
  private myfunction2(): void {
    Dialog.alert('Dialog alert is working');
  }

  private _onListViewStateChanged = (args: ListViewStateChangedEventArgs): void => {
    Log.info(LOG_SOURCE, 'List view state changed');

    const compareOneCommand: Command = this.tryGetCommand('COMMAND_1');
    if (compareOneCommand) {
      // This command should be hidden unless exactly one row is selected.
      compareOneCommand.visible = this.context.listView.selectedRows?.length === 1;
    }

    // TODO: Add your logic here

    // You should call this.raiseOnChage() to update the command bar
    this.raiseOnChange();
  }

}


What is in myfunction1()? Could you comment out those two statements and add a simple alert like alert("My simple alert"); and see what happens. I used sample at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-simple-cmdset-with-dialog-api and seeing no issues. Worked for me as expected

I posted the entire code in the original post. COMMAND_1 is only visible when a file is selected. I am trying to trigger a Power Automate flow and send the file ID of the selected file to the flow.

I'm assuming that the click event is now working for, right? Passing the ID of the selected item or file to a Power Automate is a different requirement. I think you can do that simply creating a button by using column formatting. Have you explored that option? See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68641613/calling-instant-flow-from-sharepoint-formatted-column

The click event is working, but it is not triggering the PA flow. I would rather not have the approval button as a column, but just as an action in the context menu when you right-click on a file. I suspect that my problem lies in how I'm collecting the file ID or calling the flow, but I don't see where I'm going wrong.

Okay.. have not done that.. but will take look at it and post as time permits

Please see the code sample showing:

How to extract the selected document id when Command1 is clicked
How to call a Power Automate flow and pass the selected document id for further processing

For additional info as to how to call a Power Automate from SPFX, see here
//Execute Power Automate
public ExecPowerAutomate(DocumentID?: string) {
const postURL = "Power Automate URL for When a HTTP request is received";

const body: string = JSON.stringify({
  'documentID': DocumentID,
  'emailAddress': 'TestEmail@gmail.com'
});

const requestHeaders: Headers = new Headers();

requestHeaders.append('Content-type', 'application/json');

const httpClientOptions: IHttpClientOptions = {
  body: body,
  headers: requestHeaders
};


Dialog.alert(`Calling Power Automate with DocumentID:${DocumentID}`).catch(() => {
  /* handle error */
});

this.context.httpClient.post(
  postURL,
  HttpClient.configurations.v1,
  httpClientOptions)
  .then((response: HttpClientResponse) => {        

    console.log(response.json());

  });

}
public onExecute(event: IListViewCommandSetExecuteEventParameters): void {
switch (event.itemId) {
  case 'COMMAND_1':

    console.log(event.selectedRows);

    //HOW TO RETRIEVE DOCUMENT/ITEM ID FROM THE SELECT DOCUMENT/ID
    //let documentServerRelativeUrl = event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileRef');
    //let fileName = JSON.stringify(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FileLeafRef'));
    let documentID = JSON.stringify(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('ID'));
    //let isFolder = JSON.stringify(event.selectedRows[0].getValueByName('FieldType'));

    alert("retrieved Document ID:" + documentID);

    this.ExecPowerAutomate(documentID);

    break;
  case 'COMMAND_2':
    Dialog.alert(`${this.properties.sampleTextTwo}`).catch(() => {
      /* handle error */
    });
    break;
  default:
    throw new Error('Unknown command');
}

}

